# Android 3.0 honeycomb search view on action bar

Tags: android, android-widget, android-actionbar

How to have a 'search item' on the action bar for honeycomb? If possible please provide full code with layout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean adding the search widget to the actionbar?
Here's how it's done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

This is of course placed in the res/menu folder.

You add this to your actionbar just like any adding any other menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
  // Set appropriate listeners for searchView
  ...
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This was all taken from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView